# Android App with Online Database

Tags: java, android

i'm creating an app wherein the database are uploaded online without website, the concept of the app is like Waze app. I dont know where to start im asking for ideas and help. do i need to create a web server?how?i will mark this correct for those who can answer thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a simple task because it relies on many parts doing its proper job... In order to do what you want to do you need basically 5 things:

1.- **Server**: which will feed live information to the app.(There is a ton of servers that can be used to get this part done. If you are used to, or willing to learn php, I suggest you to start researching **XAMPP** (it uses Apache server running php stuff) [https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html]).

2.- **Database**: Most likely the server will need to work with information stored in some place. databases are perfect for just that. XAMPP also comes with **MySQL** which happens to be the most popular open source database out there.

3.- **Format** :You need to determine how the information will be passed from the server to the mobile device. The most common ways are: **JSON** which is plain text, **XML** that also is plain text but formatted diferently. this is important because you have to send the information from the server using this format and also your mobile devices will need to interpret the information in this format.

4.- Choose **a way to send and recive the information** : i would suggest **Http/Ip** protocol for this, as it is very common. Investigate Http requests and responses.

5.- Your **device must be listening** (or asking) for the content : the device will have to implement some sort of **timer** to ask the server for new information. This is determined by the logic and prupose of what you wish to do.

Answer (score 0):

> do i need to create a web server?

Yes! You need to create a web server, then, a webservice (database query etc...) which communicate between your application and your webserver. I think that all!

Comment: what are the tools on creating a webserver?

Comment: It's belong to your purpose, there are many type of webserver, I'm not good about that, only give to you some idea and solution :) You can write your server by JAVA or .NET, it's belong to the operation of your server :) Anyway, read the second answer to get more information.